# Differences between new HttpLink and createHttpLink from package apollo-link-http

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

In tutorial

> https://www.howtographql.com/vue-apollo/1-getting-started/

there is presented `new HttpLink` syntax, but in official docs

> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/http/

function `createHttpLink` is applied.

None of these two sources describes the differences between these methods.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no fundamental difference between the two.

If you look at the `apollo-link-http` package source [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/blob/master/packages/apollo-link-http/src/httpLink.ts), you can see that the exported `createHttpLink` method returns a new instance of the `ApolloLink` class initialized with the options you passed to `createHttpLink` (lines 62-194).

At the end of the same file, you can see that the package also exports the `HttpLink` class, which extends the `ApolloLink` class (lines 256-261):

```
export class HttpLink extends ApolloLink {
  public requester: RequestHandler;
  constructor(opts?: HttpLink.Options) {
    super(createHttpLink(opts).request);
  }
}
```

As you can see from the code above, when you create an apollo http link by creating a new instance of the `HttpLink` class, the options you pass to the constructor are internally passed on to `createHttpLink`, which returns an instance of `ApolloLink` as mentioned above, and that instance's `RequestHandler` is passed on to (i.e. copied) to the new `HttpLink` instance's parent, which is also an instance of `ApolloLink` (see lines 96-124 [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/blob/master/packages/apollo-link/src/link.ts) for a peek at `ApolloLink`'s own constructor).

Note that the `apollo-link-http` package's own [docs](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages/apollo-link-http) do **NOT** mention the `new HttpLink` syntax, so I would stick to the `createHttpLink` syntax for future compatibility.